# Analizar directorios de una ruta

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion que analiza los ficheros y carpetas del Path donde esta instalado pero no pasa a las subcarpetas para profundizar.

La ruta del Path es "." y si hay una carpeta llamada example con ficheros dentro solo analiza la carpeta example y no profundizar

Lo hago con itedir() pero no conozco ningun parametro y si existen.

He probado con is_dir() y detecto los directorios junto con os.scandir() pero no consigo añadir mediante append a una lista en un formato tipo /root/desktop/example/

Tambien he probado con os.walk() sin fortuna.  Alguna idea.

Comment: Si compartes tu código es mas facil ayudarte...

Comment: `os.walk()` es lo que tienes que usar. ¿Cómo lo intentaste con esta y por qué no te funcionó? (nota: `iterdir()` nunca lo había oído,  busqué en google  "iterdir python" y el primer resultado es esta pregunta... mala señal)

Comment: Al usar os.walk me devuelve en resultado como el ejemplo que te pongo:

Comment: Al usar os.walk me devuelve en resultado como el ejemplo que te pongo:

.\python2\testdir\Readme_files\Lpt_Port_Config.gif
.\python2\testdir\Readme_files\ParallelPortViever.gif
.\python2\testdir\Readme_files\softcollection.css
.\python2\testdir\Readme_files\Thumbs.db
.\python2\testdir\Readme_files\
.\python2\testdir\Readme.htm
.\python2\testdir
.\Applicationdocs.docx
.\book.zip
.\foo.txt
.\java.ppt
.\python2.  El punto al inicio es lo que se guarda luego como parte de la lista y no reconoce la siguiente parte del programa ya que la sintaxis correcta es del tipo /root/

Comment: Itedir forma parte de la libreria pathlib y sirve para leer dentro de un directorio los ficheros y carpetas que hay.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema,  efectivamente con os.walk y antes con os.getcwd para establecer el directorio actual. Ahora tengo otro problema.  Necesito copiar en un txt datos y no me aparecen todos aunque si escanea todos los directorios.  Uso a y a+ pero no funciona con with open y tampoco r+,  alguna idea?

Comment: Comparte el código que has probado. No sirve de nada que digas que no te funciona si no sabemos lo que has hecho. Por cierto, mírate el módulo `pathlib`, es el modo más _pythónico_ de hacer estas cosas.